# Pausing and Unpausing Audio in A Function

Tags: javascript

My website plays music on load, but I also wanted to be able to click on the a button to pause or unpause the music. Especially for OSX where autoplay or .onload doesn't work. However I'm not sure where I went wrong with the onclick event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var audio = new Audio('/Sounds/Macintosh.mp3');
function detectmob() { 
         if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) //Checks if on mobile
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
         ){
              return true;
          }
         else {
              var audio = new Audio('/Sounds/Macintosh.mp3');
              audio.play(); 
              }
}

function Pause {
    if (audio.play = false){
    audio.play();
    }
    else {
    audio.pause();
    }


}
window.onload = detectmob;
</script>
<center> <input type="image" onclick="Pause" src="/images/button.jpg" style="width:750px;height:400px;"></center>
```

After I implemented the second function(Pause), the first function ceased to work. Now no sound is playing, irrelevant of clicking on the picture.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues.

Looks like you forgot to add the parenthesis `()` after the function name, you need those to invoke the function.

```
function Pause {
    if (audio.play = false){
    audio.play();
    }
    else {
    audio.pause();
    }
}
```

Should look like this:

```
function Pause() {
    if (audio.play = false){
    audio.play();
    }
    else {
    audio.pause();
    }   
}
```

You also forgot to add them to the onclick definition.

```
<input type="image" onclick="Pause" src="/images/button.jpg" style="width:750px;height:400px;">
```

Should be:

```
<input type="image" onclick="Pause()" src="/images/button.jpg" style="width:750px;height:400px;">
```

Your code in entirety should look like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  var audio = new Audio('/Sounds/Macintosh.mp3');

function detectmob() {
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) //Checks if on mobile
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
  ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    var audio = new Audio('/Sounds/Macintosh.mp3');
    audio.play();
  }
}

function Pause() {
  if (audio.play = false) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }


}
window.onload = detectmob();

</script> 

<center>
  <input type="image" 
               onclick="Pause()"
               src = "/images/button.jpg"
               style = "width:750px; height:400px;">
</center>
```

Comment: I changed it but it didn't affect anything.

Comment: @enki, that fixed the problem it had with the first function, Thanks! Now it plays onload. Unfortunately it still doesn't pause/unpause onclick.

Comment: @Yes Updated again with a complete example, you sure you added the parenthesis after `Pause` in the `onclick`?

Comment: @enki Thanks for you're help! The syntax was one of the problems but another one was the way I was using audio.play as true/false. Anyone else that didn't get their problem solved should check out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733162/on-and-off-audio-button-not-working-in-js