# On and Off audio button not working in JS

Tags: javascript, html, audio

So I made a script in JavaScript that would play a mp3 file and then there would be an image that you would click on to toggle whether on not the audio should play. When I click on the picture it stops playing the mp3 file which is what I wanted it to do but when I click on it again it doesn't resume or start over the song.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function detectmob() { 
         if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) //Checks if on mobile
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
         || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
         ){
              return true;
          }
         else {
                    audio.play();
              }
}
function Pause() {
         if (audio.play = false) {
            audio.play()
         }
         else {
            audio.pause();
         }
}
window.onload = detectmob;
</script>

<center> <input type="image" onclick="Pause()" src="/images/Nor.gif" style="width:750px;height:400px;"></center>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition check `audio.play = false` is wrong, it is assigning the value `false` to `play` property overriding the default function reference.

You can use the [paused](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/paused) property to check whether the audio is paused.

```
function Pause() {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks a ton! I have been working on it for an hour or 2 and i tried a bunch of different ways and i tried having it just as audio.pause and not audio.paused

Comment: @AndrewFriedman always look at the documentation to see what are the available properties/functions, don't guess